# Question about prime ideals in commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

A commutative ring $R$ can have the property that if $I\subset R$ is an ideal such that $\sqrt I=\mathfrak p$, with $\mathfrak p\subset R$ a prime ideal, then $I=\mathfrak p^n$. The notes that I'm using prove that $\mathbb Z$ has this property, and say that "this is equivalent to show that every zero-divisor in $\mathbb Z /\mathfrak p^n$, with $\mathfrak p\subset \mathbb Z$ a prime ideal, is nilpotent". Since in $\mathbb Z$ this is immediately clear, I suppose that the notes mean that if $R$ is a ring with the property above, then every zero-divisor in $R/\mathfrak p^n$ is nilpotent. Can you give me an outline of a proof of this fact? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they are alluding to is the notion of a [primary ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_ideal).

An ideal $Q$ of a commutative ring $R$ is called primary if,

> for all $a,b\in R$, if $ab\in Q$, then either $a\in Q$ or $b^n\in Q$ for some positive integer $n$.

This is easily equivalent to

> Every nonzero zero divisor in $R/Q$ is nilpotent.

In some rings (but not all) the primary ideals coincide with powers of prime ideals.

Comment: I'm reluctant to actually spell out the equivalence since it is so simple.  I can offer help if you are really stuck somehow, but I have a hard time believing you'll be stuck. It all follows according to definition.

Comment: Thank you; what you wrote is clear to me, I am actually stuck with another equivalence. My notes prove that, in $\mathbb Z$, for every ideal $I$ such that $\mathfrak p:=\sqrt I$ is prime, one has $I=\mathfrak p^n$. How can I deduce that this property, which can be rephrased as "the minimal prime ideal over an ideal $I$ is $\sqrt I$", is equivalent to "every power of a prime is primary"?

Comment: @Dorian: This last assertion is false. There is a counterexample  in *Bourbaki, Commutative Algebra*, ch. IV, §2, exercise 1 b).

Comment: @Bernard my notes prove that in $\mathbb Z$, if the minimal prime ideal over an ideal $I$ is $\mathfrak p:=\sqrt I$, then $I=\mathfrak p^n$. Then they say that this is equivalent to say that $\mathbb Z/(\mathfrak p^n)$ has only nilpotent elements as zero-divisors, i.e. $\mathfrak p$ is primary. How should I interprete this? Thanks a lot

Comment: It works in $\mathbf Z$. The counterexample is for the subring $B=\mathbf Z[2X,X^2,X^3]\subset \mathbf Z[X]$ and the prime ideal $\mathfrak p=2BX+BX^2$ : $\mathfrak p^2$ is not $\mathfrak p$-primary, albeit its root is $\mathfrak p$.

Comment: @Bernard The thing that is confusing me is the following: since $\mathbb Z$ is a principal ideal domain, is obvious that every power of a prime ideal $\mathfrak p=(p)$ is primary, because $\mathfrak p ^n=(p^n)$. However I don't understand how the notes deduce this fact (in $\mathbb Z$) by noticing that if the minimal prime ideal over an ideal $I$ is $\sqrt I$, then $I$ is a power of $\sqrt I$. Thank you

Comment: @Dorian We know that in $\mathbb Z$, a minimal prime over $I\neq\{0\}$ corresponds to a prime divisor.  The radical is prime iff there is a unique divisor, hence the generator of $I$ has only one prime divisor. Hence it is a power of that divisor.